# Insert column in alphabetical order of header name

Tags: excel, vba, alphabetical

The purpose is to copy one data column from tab A ("UserSPD Interpolation" in the code below), then paste and save in tab B ("User SPDs" in the code below).

With more data columns copied and pasted, the quantity of columns in tab B increases. The name of the data column is also copied and pasted as the column header.

Now I want to insert a new column to tab B with the header name in alphabetical order.

I have the error message

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

```vb
Sub SaveUserSPD()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("User SPDs")
With ws
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(1, lastColumn + 1)) = Sheets("Main").Range("B13").Value
    .Range(.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lastRow + 1, lastColumn + 1)) = Sheets("UserSPD Interpolation").Range("K3:K403").Value
End With

Dim x As Long, y As Long, tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("User SPDs")
' Loop through each column
With tbl.ListColumns
    For x = 1 To (tbl.ListColumns.Count - 1)
        For y = x + 1 To tbl.ListColumns.Count
            If .Item(y).Name < .Item(x).Name Then
                .Item(y).Range.Cut
                .Item(x).Range.Insert xlRight
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End With

Range("B13").Value = ""
Range("B16:C5015").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920697/macro-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range

Comment: It is the "Set tbl" line that gives error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use range.transpose function. try code below on temp workbook. u need have sheet named Arkusz1 and another sheet named TEMP

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng_SourceRange As Range, rng_TranspozeRange As Range

Set rng_SourceRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(1, 1), _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

Set rng_TranspozeRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMP").Cells(1, 1).Resize(rng_SourceRange.Columns.Count, rng_SourceRange.Rows.Count)

rng_TranspozeRange.Value = Application.Transpose(rng_SourceRange)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMP").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMP").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=transposeRng.Columns(1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMP").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMP").Cells
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    'transposeRng.Clear
    rng_SourceRange.Clear
    rng_SourceRange.Value = Application.Transpose(rng_TranspozeRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. But is there a way to fix it within just one Module? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes code below. i kept sheets names which you used and code fragment where you place new column in sheet. note that range of added column you define last row of target sheet +1. if you have more data rows in column it wouldnt be pasted.

```
Sub AddColumnAndSort()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_UserSPDs As Worksheet, ws_Main As Worksheet, ws_UserSPDI As Worksheet
    Dim ws_TEMP As Worksheet    '   TEMPORARY SHEET
    Dim lng_LastRow As Long, lng_LastColumn As Long
    Dim rng_SourceRange As Range, rng_TranspozeRange As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_UserSPDs = wb.Worksheets("User SPDs")    '   target sheet where column will be add and sort
    Set ws_Main = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    Set ws_UserSPDI = wb.Worksheets("UserSPD Interpolation")
    Set ws_TEMP = wb.Worksheets("TEMP")
    
    With ws_UserSPDs
        lng_LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lng_LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, lng_LastColumn + 1), .Cells(1, lng_LastColumn + 1)) = ws_Main.Range("B13").Value
        .Range(.Cells(2, lng_LastColumn + 1), .Cells(lng_LastRow + 1, lng_LastColumn + 1)) = ws_UserSPDI.Range("K3:K403").Value
        lng_LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lng_LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    Set rng_SourceRange = ws_UserSPDs.Range(ws_UserSPDs.Cells(1, 1), ws_UserSPDs.Cells(lng_LastRow, lng_LastColumn))
    Set rng_TranspozeRange = ws_TEMP.Cells(1, 1).Resize(rng_SourceRange.Columns.Count, rng_SourceRange.Rows.Count)

    rng_TranspozeRange.Value = Application.Transpose(rng_SourceRange)

    ws_TEMP.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws_TEMP.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng_TranspozeRange.Columns(1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws_TEMP.Sort
        .SetRange ws_TEMP.Cells
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    rng_SourceRange.Clear
    rng_SourceRange.Value = Application.Transpose(rng_TranspozeRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tomasz. Let me try it :)